# Writing to a file in C with two fprintf statements

Tags: c, file, file-io, printf, file-writing

I'm trying to write two different things to a file: an array of over 1,000 elements, and the average and median of the elements. I can print the array fine, but when I try to add the median or mean to it, the program quits partway through printing the array to the console and doesn't print to the file. This is my code:

```
char fName[20] = "file";
               /*creating a file*/
               fp=fopen(fName,"w");
               int q = 0;
               while ( q<num ) {
                   fprintf(fp, "%.3f\n", mergedArray[q]);
                   q++;

               }
```

//the above part works fine. the part below is what i can't seem to figure
     out. I've tried putting it underneath the q++; of the while statement but that also crashed it.

```
fprintf("The median: %lf \nThe average: %lf", &median, &avg);

// Close the file
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: What are the types of `median` and `avg`?

Comment: You're missing `fp` to your second `fprintf`.

Comment: With a high enough warning level, your compiler might have told you that the first parameter to `fprintf` needs to be a `FILE*`, not `char*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` doesn't take an address for floats.  Try this;

```
fprintf(fp, "The median: %lf \nThe average: %lf", median, avg);
```